# AWS CodeArtifact - Is there a way to define LifeCycle policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codeartifact

I have configured a domain with a few repos - maven, npm, gradle and google-android. I was looking for controls that would help manage content lifecycle and could not find any..

ex: In case of [Maven repos with Artifactory we could do this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Managing+Disk+Space+Usage#ManagingDiskSpaceUsage-LimitingtheNumberofSnapshots).. or in case of [Nexus we could define Cleanup Policies](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/repository-management/cleanup-policies)

Answer (score 4):

It is early days for this service and this ability is not there, currently customers may need to use ListPackageVersions and DeletePackageVersions APIs inside lambda for example to cleanup unused packages.

Comment:  It was early days when this answer was written. Still seems like AWS didn't think cleanup was going to be a thing.